# Buying a canon 5d Mark II with 120 000 shutter actuations?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon-5d-mark-ii

Would you consider buying a used canon 5d Mark II in mint condition with 120 000 shutter actuations for 500$? The seller is a nice lady, she is a professional phototographer. Here are some photos of the camera that she has sent me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related question: [How many actuations are "too many actuations"?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/3813)

Comment: Camera looks clean. I found one on eBay for 1200 that's brand new. Given a few hundreds bucks for a shutter replacement on this one, you'd still be quite far from 1200. Seems like a decent deal to me!

Comment: 120000 is a lottery: it may broke next week or may work years and years. In our country the shutter replacement will cost 800 - 900 dollars. I suggest it may be good deal.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, how is that a good deal when you could buy the camera itself for that price instead of just a shutter?

Comment: @walther I cannot buy that old camera for 800-900 bucks in my country (Too old and broken is not for sale, in good conditions can cost more). It consts more than that summ. But repairing will be with 1 year garantie and with ckecking of all other parts. So I think that is good deal.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to equate shutter click counts with car mileage. To me, your question's equivalent car shopping question is: Would you buy a 2008/2009 used car with 120,000 miles on it for 1/5 of what it went for new?

You may also want to look at [this website](https://www.olegkikin.com/shutterlife/canon_eos5dmkii.htm):

[image]

The graph is based on a survey from 5DMkII owners, who navigated to the site themselves, about when their shutters failed/are still alive. The page states:

> Average number of actuations after which shutter is still alive: 137,709.5
>
> Average number of actuations after which shutter died: 171,076.9

It looks like the failure rates begin to increase right bang on the 100,000 mark, which is the typical lifespan spec for Canon's shutter mechanism, iirc.

Based on a Kaplan-Meier statistical analysis of the submitted data, you have about a 3 in 4 chance of making it to between 250,000 and 500,000 and a 2 in 3 chance of making it to between 500,000 and 1,000,000 actuations. There's only about a 1 in 8 chance that the shutter will fail at between 100,000 and 150,000 actuations. Canon rates the shutter of the EOS 5D Mark II at 150,000 actuations.